# Group management - Site owner ability to add to other group except its own

Tags: 2010, permissions, groups

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the following scenario:

In each subsite, there are three groups:
`Site Owners`
`Site Authors`
`Site Readers`

I'd like to have only the site collection admins to be able to add someone to the `Site Owners` group.
Those in the `Site Owners` group can make anyone a `Site Author` or a `Site Reader`, but I don't want them to be able to add someone as a `Site Owner`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can get this, as Site owners having the Full control rights and full control can Manage Permissions  -  Create and change permission levels on the Web site and assign permissions to users and groups.

Unless if you create another permission level but i am afraid if you remove Manage Permissions then site owners will not be able to manager permissions.

Check more about permission.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262690(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I've thought as much. Thanks for the confirmation.